# AbpDbContext and IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, abp

I have an ASP.NET Core (v. 2.2) application that uses `IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string>`.

I'm adding **Abp Framework** to the application, I want to use `AbpDbContext`.

How to combine the functionality of two contexts?

Comment: your AbpDbContext should inherit from IdentityDbContext

Comment: AbpDbContext already inherit from DbContext.

Comment: so what's the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a module class like below

```
public class BlogModule : AbpModule
{

}
```

and add your other module dependency in the attribute. Something like this

```
[DependsOn(typeof(BlogModule))]
public class WebAppModule : AbpModule
{

}
```

And read https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Module-Development-Basics